# Apache ambari componets?

Tags: java

I just started into hadooop. I am using apche ambari for managing my cluster. I want to know the programming languages and tools (Java) used for ambari ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the langulages and tools used :

### Languages :

Java - For implementing ambari server and webservises

Java script : - For ambari server ui

Python - For ambari agents

Shell script : For configuring services

### Tools :

Ganglia : For collecting matrics like cpu, network usage

Puppet : For starting and stopping hadoop services

Nagios : For sending alerts incase of any service is down